# Is it ok to use the official iPhone compose icon on the tab bar of my app?

Tags: iphone, icons, tabbar

I have a tab bar for my app. One of the tab is an "action" tab for which I would like to use the official iPhone compose icon [here](http://www.apple.com/lae/iphone/tips/images/draft_icon_20100624.jpg) as the tab item icon, is it allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is allowed provided you use it they way it was intended to be used. So if it is used to initiate a "compose" feature it would be allowed.

Apple will not hesitate to reject an app if any of their icons are used in unintended or nonstandard ways - and will site their [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html). So if you aren't sure, I would suggest just creating something very similar yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The compose item is a bar button system item, not a tab bar item. I think you will run into HIG issues with it - it is typically used to summon a modal controller for you to create an item (usually a message).

That doesn't really fit as a tab bar item, which suggests a view of information that you can switch into or out of at any time.

In addition, the graphic may not be in the correct proportion or have the right properties to use in a tab bar.